# Usage of the preposition "auf"

Tags: standard-german

Duden lists "zur Angabe des Grundes, der Voraussetzung" as a definition of "auf." Can someone clarify what it means by this? I understand that the translation literally means "to specify the reasons, conditions" but I'm unclear on how it's used. Maybe some more examples?

Examples provided:

- > **auf** Veranlassung, Initiative seiner Mutter, von seiner Mutter
- > **auf** wiederholte Aufforderung [hin]
- > **auf** einen Brief antworten

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition

Answer (score 3):

The explanation you found in Duden is correct, but it is very abstract, and so I am not surprised that you have problems understanding it. Indeed, seeing more examples could be helpful:

> Auf Initiative seiner Mutter bewarb sich Heinz beim Bäcker als Geselle.

On (!) his mother's initiative, Heinz applied for an apprenticeship at the baker's.

> Auf Veranlassung des Betriebsrats befasste sich die Werksleitung mit dem Vorfall.

At the instigation of the works committee, the works management concerned itself with the incident.

> Auf einen Brief antworten.

To answer "on" a letter / to answer a letter.

More examples :

> Aufgrund des schlechten Wetters...

Due to the bad weather... ("On grounds" of the bad weather...)

> Auf deinen Rat hin habe ich mir den grünen Pulli gekauft.

On your advice I bought the green pullover.

(I don't know if you would say that so, with "on" in English, really, but I think it still makes the meaning, clear, doesn't it?)

> Auf Ersuchen des Dorfvorstehers gestattete der Landrat den Festumzug.

On request of the village headman the governour gave permission for the pageant.

**Learning German: better memorize expressions**

If what you are doing is learning German, I would doubt that you have much use of learning theoretical categorizations of meanings (here for the preposition "auf"). I think it will be more useful to memorize some concrete and frequently used expressions in some context, and use them actively.

Note that expressions like *auf Veranlassung seiner Mutter*, *auf Initiative des Pfarrers* and so on are from a rather bureaucratic register of speech. People do not speak like this in everyday communication. Rather you can find such expressions in formal letters, like business letters.

**Expressions for everyday situations:**

> auf Rechnung  = to buy not cash but on (!) account 
>   auf Rezept (Medikamente kaufen)
>   auf deinen Rat hin
>   auf eigene Gefahr
>   auf eigene Rechnung 
>   auf Gedeih und Verderb
>   auf Teufel komm raus
>   auf Nimmerwiedersehen
>   auf Wiedersehen
>   auf gut Glück
>   auf Schritt und Tritt
>   auf Heller und Pfennig (= einen Geldbetrag sehr genau ausrechnen oder auszahlen)

In all these cases (or idioms) you can argue - as Duden would do - that here the *auf* introduces some condition under which the action takes place. But knowing this does not help you (nor a native speaker). What helps is knowing the expressions as such, and their meaning and typical use-cases.

---

If anybody feels competent to improve my English translations: welcome!

Comment: Thank you, very good answer. Would you mind explaining how "Auf einen Brief antworten" introduces a condition? The rest of the answer makes very good sense though!

Comment: @Aaron  The core idea I wanted to share here was that the approach of explaning meanings of *auf* via a logical deducation (from a universal rule to concrete use-cases) is not really helpful at all. You anyway will have to learn these expressions individually, together with situations where you would typcially use them. Anyway, if you insist I can try to find a logcial explanation for *auf einen Brief antworten* being about a *condition* (in the sense of circumstance). A person answers. What does he/she answer? A letter. So, the letter is a condition specifiying the action.

Comment: ... but please be aware that with this ad hoc attempt of an explanation I am simply trying to forcefully pump logic into a phenomenon that perhaps is not that logical by nature at all. I would guess that the deductive rule Duden offeres was created inductively (starting from a number of expressions where *auf* can be seen as being used to describve the condition of an action). Still there are other meanings of *auf* (e.g. simply: physical position on top of something. Now clearly, the answering is not *physically on top of* the letter. There might be other meanings of *auf* that fit better...

Comment: ... Or I am simply wrong, and *auf einen Brief* is not a condition of *antworten* is not a condition but something else. Probably we are here in an area thats not to be defined by truth, rather by opinion. .